# How can I use "dash.properties.Synced" in the Dash web app? | Python

Tags: python, tabs, synchronization, store, plotly-dash

I'm referring to [this post](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/844) so that I can use data from different tabs in the Dash web app.
But I couldn't use `dash.properties.Synced` and getting the error `AttributeError: module 'dash' has no attribute 'properties'`.

##### Sample Code

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_daq as daq

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config["suppress_callback_exceptions"] = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id="num_output", storage_type='session',),
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab one', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab two', value='tab-2'),
    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-example-content')
])


@app.callback(Output('tabs-example-content', 'children'),
              Input('tabs-example', 'value'))
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Tab content 1'),
            # dcc.Store(id="num_output", storage_type='local',),  # session, local
            html.Div(id="num_output2",),
            html.Div([daq.NumericInput(
                id="num_input",
                label='Vehicles',
                labelPosition='top',
                value=dash.properties.Synced(
                    id='store_model',
                    property='data',
                    default=4
                ),
            ), ], style={'marginLeft': 20, 'marginRight': 20, 'width': '5%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-2':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Tab content 2'),
            html.Div(id="num_output2",),
        ])


@app.callback(
    Output('num_output', 'data'),
    Input('num_input', 'value'))
def render_content(data):
    return data


@app.callback(
    Output('num_output2', 'children'),
    Input('num_output', 'modified_timestamp'),
    State('num_output', 'data'))
def render_content(ts, data):
    if data:
        return html.H4(f'out {data}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The example code with dash.properties.Synced is not a real API, it is a made-up suggestion from the poster as a possible way to help solve the problem.

I'm not aware of anyone taking this idea forwards.

It is possible to share state across tabs by using global and local 'store' objects that you write-to when updating from within a tab, and that you read-from when drawing the content on the tab.  See my attempt at describing this on the [original post](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/844)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess you are "ncorran". Can you share a sample code to demonstrate your implementation. It would help me understand the concept. Thanks.